# Opening vbproj and sln files leads to visual studio open

Tags: vb.net

I searched about vjproj and sln files in general on this website.
I understand why they exist.

However, my question is, when I open those files in sublime text, I see the xml or something else clearly (or anything they are supposed to show). But when  I double click them, they just lead to usual visual studio environment. And I don't understand why executing those two files make visual studio open even though they are supposed to be markup languages?

Thank you!

Comment: They are not XML files but Visual studio files and the default opening program is rightly Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS only care about the [file's extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) to pick which application responsible for handling that file. In most case, `.vbproj` and `.sln` are associated with Visual Studio application no matter the file's content. To test this behavior, try to rename the file's extension to `.xml` and it will be treated as XML file.

Comment: Thank you very much. OS only cares about extension!